# Why doesn't this give me the object I expected .. which is {1:2} Instead the console gives {a:2}

Tags: javascript, object

Why doesn't this give me the object I expected .. which is {1:2} Instead the console gives {a:2}

```
function createObject (a, b) {
    const myObject = {a:b}
    console.log(myObject);
}

createObject(1, 2);
```

Comment: Should be `{[a]: b}` since you want to evaluate `a` as an expression rather than an identifier/key

Comment: @Paul Thank you! That solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without brackets, the property name of a literal object is not evaluated as an expression:

```js
function createObject (a, b) {
    const myObject = {[a]: b}
    console.log(myObject);
}

createObject(1, 2);
```